# Why am I getting an “input not found error” on every display I attempt to plug-in to my PC?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, display

I got my PC down from the attic the other day. Plugged it in, and it powers up. The fans are all running, including the graphics card fan. Lights are on and the motherboard is lit up too.

I have then tried to boot numerous times, using a TV, multiple monitors, and all the available port types VGA, DVI & HDMI.

One of the monitors and cables I grabbed from the missus who uses it daily so we know the HDMI and VGA cables work along with the TV and one of the monitors. It isn't the displays or a cable being broken.

In each monitors own terms I am told that the input signal is not found.
I have taken out and reseated the graphics card multiple times, and rebooted numerous times.

Could it be that the DVI cable that I dug out with the PC is broken and the PC is set to specifically use DVI output and is not able to swap freely between HDMI, VGA & DVI?

Anyone able to suggest what to do next?

Comment: Does it have any onboard graphics option? What CPU is it? If there are two outputs, onboard & PCI, it should be smart enough to auto-switch if the first choice is unavailable.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas :O Won't that break it more? :S

Comment: @Tetsujin - It is an ASUS motherboard, with a ATI Radeon 5870 Black edition GPU.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my questions. It's the CPU/onboard graphics that is the key here.

Comment: @Tetsujin how could I find the information you need buddy?

Comment: "Tetsujin how could I find the information you need buddy"  Make and Model of PC?

Comment: @Moab: I would think that a computer was stored in the attic because it became unusable. Jason: This job is for a repairman, but might not be worth the cost.

Comment: @harrymc - No, it was stored in the attic as there was no room for it. I have since found a space for it!

Comment: Some part of your computer is faulty. The possible reasons are myriad, and it could be any of several components. You really should have a competent local PC hardware technician look at the machine.

Comment: @music2myear reporting for duty. The graphics card is dead! The whole machine is not worth much, time to buy a new rig! Wish me luck getting ahold of a good GPU.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the graphics card is dead, therefore the problem is due to a hardware failure.

Comment: @karel I agree, I have tried everything under the sun to no avail.